# Where to find description for @hi and @lo "instructions" of OR1K assembly

Tags: assembly, risc

I'm learning OR1K assembly for a project I'm working on. `clang` and `LLVM` are used to provide front end and the back end for the compiler. I found [this link](https://sourceware.org/cgen/gen-doc/openrisc-insn.html) and it is almost everything I need, however assembly I'm looking at has `@hi` and `@lo` symbols in it. I have intuitive understanding of these "instructions" do but it would be better to get official explanation of what they mean.

Below are the C and the corresponding assembly code that was generated for it.
The assembly lines I'm talking about are almost at the bottom. Here is how they look

```
l.sw    0(r1), r11
l.movhi r3, hi(.L.str@hi)
l.jal   printf
l.ori   r3, r3, lo(.L.str@lo)
```

C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int sum(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf("Hello World! %d\n", sum(argc, 1));
  return 0;
}
```

Assembly Code

```
    .text
    .file   "hello_world.ll"
    .globl  _Z3sumii
    .align  4
    .type   _Z3sumii,@function
_Z3sumii:                               # @_Z3sumii
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    l.sw    -4(r1), r2
.Ltmp0:
    .cfi_offset 2, -4
    l.addi  r2, r1, 0
.Ltmp1:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 2
    l.addi  r1, r1, -12
    l.sw    -8(r2), r3
    l.sw    -12(r2), r4
    l.lwz   r3, -8(r2)
    l.add   r11, r3, r4
    l.addi  r1, r2, 0
    l.jr    r9
    l.lwz   r2, -4(r1)
.Ltmp2:
    .size   _Z3sumii, .Ltmp2-_Z3sumii
    .cfi_endproc

    .globl  main
    .align  4
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    l.sw    -4(r1), r9
.Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset 9, -4
    l.sw    -8(r1), r2
.Ltmp4:
    .cfi_offset 2, -8
    l.addi  r2, r1, 0
.Ltmp5:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 2
    l.addi  r13, r1, -32
    l.srli  r13, r13, 3
    l.slli  r1, r13, 3
    l.movhi r5, 0
    l.sw    20(r1), r5
    l.sw    16(r1), r3
    l.sw    8(r1), r4
    l.lwz   r3, 16(r1)
    l.jal   _Z3sumii
    l.addi  r4, r0, 1
    l.sw    0(r1), r11
    l.movhi r3, hi(.L.str@hi)
    l.jal   printf
    l.ori   r3, r3, lo(.L.str@lo)
    l.movhi r11, 0
    l.addi  r1, r2, 0
    l.lwz   r9, -4(r1)
    l.jr    r9
    l.lwz   r2, -8(r1)
.Ltmp6:
    .size   main, .Ltmp6-main
    .cfi_endproc

    .type   .L.str,@object          # @.str
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.L.str:
    .asciz  "Hello World! %d\n"
    .size   .L.str, 17
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Presumably documented in the manual of your assembler. The stock GNU binutils don't seem to support OR1K so I assume you got some patched version.

Comment: I probably should add that I'm using `clang/llvm` and not gcc

Answer (score 2):

OpenRISC like many assembly languages can only use 16 bit immediate values.  So to do a load it first loads the high 16 bits and then performs an or operation on the low 16 bits. In psuedo-C:

```
int32_t addr = &str;
register r3;
r3 = addr & 0xFFFF0000; /* load hi bits, note this is a 16 bit value */
r3 |= addr &0xFFFF; /* load the lo bits of addr, note again only a 16 bit value */
```

Then what on earth is going on with that printf call either side of the load of r3?  Well, OpenRISC has a [branch delay slot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot#Branch_delay_slots).  So the call to printf happens *after* the or instruction.